# How can I open a .rds file from ArrayExpress using readRDS?

Tags: r

I'm starting to learn single cell analysis in R and I'm trying to open a .rds file in R, but I always get the message of error

How can I open it?

Processed data was downloaded from the ArrayExpress website: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biostudies/arrayexpress/studies/E-MTAB-6149?query=E-MTAB-6149#processed-data

readRDS("~/Alveolar.Cellview.Rds")
Error in readRDS("~/Alveolar.Cellview.Rds") :  unknown input format

Comment: Just to be clear, these files do not come from EMBL, they were uploaded by the study authors (who are affiliated with KU Leuven); they are merely *hosted* on ArrayExpress.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason its not an `RDS` "R-data-structure" file but and "Rda" file type which is wrongly named.

use `load` instead of `readRDS`

```
load("~/Alveolar.Cellview.Rds")
```

without assigning to a aviable.